# Integrating Crash Analytics in React Native from 'react-native-firebase'

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I successfully went through RNfirebase docs and added the libraries in my project. Everything is working well and good and the app starts. It's now basically for `android`.

I have only integrated it the way docs said i.e natively in Gradle files and wherever the docs said.

The question is do I have to initialize any method somewhere in my JS codes to record the crash events or they would be automatically sent to firebase console without requiring any codes (Which I think its impossible because I have to take their instance somewhere and then render them so that they call the native modules).

Well there are some methods which I could see in the [docs](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.0.x/crashlytics/reference/crashlytics#Methods). How to use them to record events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have included `google-services.json` by which the firebase will be initialized.

After doing `Crashalytics` setup you are good to go. You will be automatically getting crash notifications in the console.

Check this [documentation](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/crashlytics) . Even though this is for V6 it applies for all versions. We had used another such service called [Bugsnag](https://bugsnag.com), which is not as elegant as `Crashalytics`, that used to send to its console as well without we calling their send APIs.

So basically you do not need to call their APIs when crash occurs, `Crashalytics` will automatically send the crash report.

Please look to this [link](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/crashlytics/android) also.

Comment: A small ques, does this works for debug build also? Or only for production ones?

Comment: I am not sure about crashalytics, but bugsnag used to work for both.. I think even this should work for both

Comment: I just completed that. It works only on `release mode`